# JS creating a conflict with WP for a slideshow

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm getting an issue with a javascript slideshow that I wish to embed in a WP header.

Here is the slideshow designed and ready to use: http://coachjoelleinc.com/wp-content/themes/32950/rotator/test.html

And this is where I want to embed it: http://coachjoelleinc.com/index_real.php/

In older versions of Firefox it disables other plugins, such as the navigation.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: whats the error? have you tried debugging with firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking fine in Chrome for me but the issues with older browsers might be caused by the fact you've loaded the jQuery library twice.  Wordpress is loading the version that came with it (1.7.2) but prior to that version 1.5.1 is being loaded - probably by your theme's header.php rather than a plugin, the file is in the themes directory.

Bear in mind you have to load jQuery before you load all the scripts that rely on it, so if you remove the older version which is being loaded first you will need to make sure the other dependant scripts load are moved so they are loaded after the newer version of the jQuery library is loaded.

There are various ways to do that - you can enqueue them in functions.php, or move those scripts into the footer.  A quick Google comes up the [Codex Javascript guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) along with some examples of [including JS in Wordpress](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)

Comment: Thanks McNab, I will see if I can get my head around this.